# OCaml: Set function signature to that of another function

Tags: ocaml

Let's say I have an on_event function that accepts a handler function that is called when the event occurs. Now I want to write several different event handler functions that I can pass into that on_event function. Is it possible to specify a signature type in the on_event file which I can then set as the signature (in the mli files) of these other functions? This way if I need to change the signature, I'll only need to do it in one place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give a name to a type:

```
type handler = int -> unit
```

If you put this definition into a module named event.ml, then other modules can name the type as `Event.handler`.

Note that OCaml will infer types in almost all cases. You don't usually need to specify types for functions. But it's good as documentation.

**Update**

Here's one way to specify the type of a function when defining it:

```
let (f: handler) = fun n -> Printf.printf "%d\n" n
```

Comment: Follow up question:

I define a function's signature in an mli file to be type handler as defined above. I get a signature conflict between the ml and mli file because my handler function is of type int->unit and not of type handler. How can I tell ocaml that the function in ml is of type handler?

Comment: With the above definition, the types `handler` and `int -> unit` are the same. An OCaml `type` definition like the above introduces a synonym, not a new type. However, it *is* a little tricky to specify the type of a function. See update.